# Anko plugin can not run in Androidstudio version > 2.1

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I just want to learn kotlin,But when I download the anko plugin and restart my Android studio,I found that I can not open my project, I found  that Android studio which has version > 2.1 can not run anko, and I also don not want to download a Android studio 2.1，I use Android studio 2.3

Comment: Have you tried Android Studio 3.0 Beta which has Kotlin support built in: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-studio-3-0-canary1.html

Comment: In what way can you not open your project? Do you get any specific error when trying to open it?

Comment: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: 
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: 
org/jetbrains/Android/uipreview/AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager 
[Plugin: org.jetbrain.kotlin.android.dsl]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `Anko` with Android Studio 2.3.2.

I think, i also had same problem but when i used whole dependency:
`compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.0"`

But when i switch it to `compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.0"` it works.

I know it does not contains all the things, but it works for sth as much as i need.

Hope it helps.